# Backbone "reset" collection trigger not firing

Tags: backbone.js

Im using backbone.js to get a collection from the REST server. Fetch triggers fine and fills the collection with the data. However, the "reset" trigger is never fired and so addAll() is never called. Calling addAll() manually works fine - but why isn't "reset" firing as it should when fetch() is called on the collection?

Here is the code:

### Model

```
define(['backbone-tastypie'], function(Backbone) {
    var Machine = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function(){
            return this.get('resource_uri') || this.collection.url;
        }
    });

    return Machine;
});
```

### Collection

```
define(['backbone-tastypie','models/machine'], function(Backbone, Machine) {
    var Machines = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: Machine,
        url: '/api/rest/machine/',
        parse: function(data){
            return data.objects;
        }
    });

    return Machines;
});
```

### Model View

```
define(['underscore','backbone-tastypie'], function(_, Backbone) {
    var MachineTableEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        template: _.template($('#machine-row-template').html()),

        render: function(){
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            console.log('lol');
            return this;
        }   
    }); 

    return MachineTableEntryView;
});
```

### Main View

```
define(['underscore','backbone-tastypie','collections/machines','views/machine_table_entry'], function(_, Backbone, Machines, MachineTableEntryView) {
    var MachineTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#app'),

        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');

            Machines.bind('reset', this.addAll);

            this.machines = new Machines();
            this.machines.fetch();
        },

        addAll: function(){
            this.machines.each(this.addOne);
        },

        addOne: function(machine){  
            var view = new MachineTableEntryView({model:machine});
            this.$('#machines').append(view.render().el);
        },
    });

    return MachineTableView;
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to bind the event listener to the instance of the collection you create, not the Collection constructor:

```
define(['underscore','backbone-tastypie','collections/machines','views/machine_table_entry'], function(_, Backbone, Machines, MachineTableEntryView) {
var MachineTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#app'),

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');

        this.machines = new Machines();
        this.machines.bind('reset', this.addAll);
        this.machines.fetch();
    },

    addAll: function(){
        this.machines.each(this.addOne);
    },

    addOne: function(machine){  
        var view = new MachineTableEntryView({model:machine});
        this.$('#machines').append(view.render().el);
    },
});

return MachineTableView;
```